# Can Interharmonics Be FFT Artifacts?

Tags: fft

I know non-sinusoidal waveforms can be decomposed into a sum of higher integer harmonics, but are there any mechanisms that cause interharmonics?

I collected some noisy data from a source that was forced at a known frequency. I applied a Blackman-windowed FFT and found not only many integer harmonics, but also 1/5 integer harmonics (ie, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1., 1.2, 1.4, etc). Are there any signal processing causes of fractional harmonics, or should I be looking for a physical mechanism?

Comment: I deal with interharmonics in my project, they are caused by transformer saturation, a non-linear process. My intution would be that interharmonics are generally caused by non-linear processes.

Comment: this sounds like a beat between your window and the sampling of your signal , does this persist for different grid sampling?

Comment: @bla, I'm using my scope's built in spectrum conversion which doesn't appear to have any controllable parameters for the window, other than choosing which type of window to use. Would switching window type be a suitable alternative?

Comment: you didn't give enough details in the question to really answer. but try to see what is the sample length vs frequency you detect. I cant really say a lot more without knowing the conditions by which you get this artifact, or maybe it is something else in your measurement, such as picking up some 60 Hz signal that happens to be 1/5  of your window size etc. we know pretty much nothing about what you measure and how you measure it.